# Setting the height of just one static UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

Im trying to set the height of a static UITableViewCell IBOutlet in Swift. Is this possible? I have found answers to how to change all cells in a tableview, but I just want to change this one and keep the rest as they are sized in the IB.

I've tried this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        return CGFloat(screenSize.width)
    }
    else{   
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the height dynamically on a static TableViewCell, you have to indeed set it in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Here is one implementation to change the **second** row in the **first** section:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        // Here return a number for the height you desire
        return CGFloat(100)
    }
    else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

Here are a few pointers that might be relevant to your situation. Please disregard them if they where done on purpose in your code..

The height for the cell was set to the width of the screen, it might be worthwhile to check if that was intended. Also please remember that both sections and rows start at index 0 and not at index 1.

Comment: This doesnt work, since return UITableViewAutomaticDimension sets every other row to the default size of 42 (Or whatever it is) even though they have other sizes

Comment: Are the sizes different for each one?

Comment: Yes they are @Tokuriku

Comment: Then you can check for each `indexPath.row` in an `if, else if, else` format  and assign the right height for each of them :)